# How handle unsubscribe event from Appstore

Tags: ios, event-handling, in-app-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase

I coded an ios app with a subscription system but I absolutely need to know when a user unsubscribes.

I haven't found how to handle unsubscribe events with NodeJS or whatever, could someone tell me how to do this?

Also, I only save the user's phone number in the database.
Just with the phone number I would be able to find out who is unsubscribing or should I also register their apple id?

Comment: The server notification will include the original transaction identifier. You need to record that in your database when the user initially subscribes. Then you can match events back to an original subscription transaction.

Comment: Thanks !
Juste for curiosity, if one day i want publish the app on play store too, i will be forced to have two part in backend (one for play store and one for apple sotre) or an API that supports the unsubscribe events for both exists?

Comment: You can look at a service like revenuecat to help manage this.

Comment: I will look, thanks